# How to search for multiple, independant, lines in Notepad++

Tags: search, notepad++, multiple-columns, lines

I have 2 text files, one is the old txt file containing hashes with numbers after the ":", the other newer one consists of more different lines of hashes, without numbers after the ":"

I'm trying to compare the two files, to link the numbers after the ":" on the old file to the lines on the new file (after the ":")

The old text file is something like this:

- 326e3e78:50002010200392
- 473e9a83:83928372818828
- 892d8s28:37263826738273
- 893g7k19:23623283723617

Whilst the new text file is like this:
326e3e78: <- This line is there on the old file, and includes numbers after the ":"

- 563g4e26: <- This line isn't there on the old file
- 892d8s28: <- This line is there on the old file, and includes numbers after the ":"
- 893g7k19: <- This line is there on the old file, and includes numbers after the ":"

I've tried using npptoolbucket, as the built-in search function of np++ doesn't support multi-line searching.
However, everytime I try to search one of these hashes, the toolbucket isn't able to find any of them.

Could anyone help me out?
thanks in advance!

p.s: explanation might be unclear, I'm happy to add some things.

Comment: Npp is not the right tool for such job, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: @Toto thanks for the heads up! I am, however, pretty new to coding/scripts, so I wouldn't know where to start. I am ready to learn.

Comment: @marnix409 – for this, use Excel's `VLOOKUP()` function. If your file has many records so Excel will be too slow, you might want to prefer loading the values into the database and joining them there.